# How would I add text before the numbers in odometer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [odometer.js](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/) library and I want to add a '$' right before the display of numbers. (EX: $123,435) Does anyone know how to go about this to get it to work? I have tried adding  tags and inserting it in the options section of the javascrip which is in correlation with the library, but it still will not work. I have also tried :before and :after pseudos but that is not very dynamic.

```
<div class="odometer" id="odometer"></div>
```

```
.odometer {
    color: rgba(250,250,250,.75);
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position:fixed; top: -50px; width:100%; border: 0px solid black !important;
}

.odometer:before {
    content: "$";
}
```

Comment: I think the best option is CSS :before pseudo-selector.

Comment: When I put the :before selector is aligns the '$'  on top of the text. How do I get both elements to be in-line?

Comment: Post your code, this should be simple, see https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/8yaj7s6z/

Comment: I just added the code to the post.

Comment: Your code work fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tuqhmok1/. If you don't get it working in your real environment, then update this working example showing your problem.

Comment: I think the problem lies somewhere in the odometer.js code. The example you have works well but it's not including the framework for the odometer effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.odometer-inside:before {
    content: "$";
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tuqhmok1/1/

Comment: You are welcome, I found the solution in the HTML generated by the plugin.